# Adding object into a list with function

Tags: python, oop

Is it possible to write a function inside class `myClass` that will add created objects into a list?
I have wrote `def addInList(self):` but I do not know how to get a created object so that I can append it into a list.

I want to have a program that will create an object when you call a function, and that will automaticly append it into a list.

This is the code:

```
class myClass:

    def __init__(self, name, city):

        self.name = name
        self.city = city

    def addInList(self):
        pass


    def __str__(self):

        return "Name: {}\nCity: {}\n".format(self.name, self.city)


First = myClass("Mike","New York")
Second = myClass("Steve", "Los Angeles")

print(First)
print(Second)
```

I want to have a list of objects, so that when I print the list i get list of all created objects.

Comment: It's unclear what you want exactly. Provide some input and expected output.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: >>I want to have a program that will create an object when you call a function, and that will automatically append it into a list.<< Correct me if I am wrong but you want to have an object that has a method that will create this object itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize a list in `__init__(self)` and append to this list in the method:

```
class myClass:

    def __init__(self, name, city):
        self.name = name
        self.city = city
        self.lst = []

    def addInList(self):
        self.lst.extend([self.name, self.city])
```

Now, you can create objects like you did and call the function `addInList()`.  `<object>.lst` gives the list created.

```
First = myClass("Mike","New York")
First.addInList()

print(First.lst)
# ['Mike', 'New York']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class myClass():

    list_of_instances = []

    def __init__(self, name, city):    
        self.name = name
        self.city = city     

    def __str__(self):
        return "Name: {}\nCity: {}\n".format(self.name, self.city)

    def addInList(self):
        self.list_of_instances.append(self)

First = myClass("Mike","New York")
Second = myClass("Steve", "Los Angeles")
First.addInList()

print(First.list_of_instances)    
# [<__main__.myClass at 0x7fee69cd6c18>]

Second.addInList()

for i in First.list_of_instances:
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
Name: Mike
City: New York

Name: Steve
City: Los Angeles
```

Comment: Thanks my friend !
Is there a way to create an object with function?

Comment: @VoidBeats - please open new question or clarify this with required output